# Windows 10 error 0x80070780 on file delete

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I have been locked out from my Windows 10 account.
I created a dummy account for Microsoft and now I'm locked out of Windows 10.

I've installed Windows 7 along with Windows 10 to regain control of Windows 10.
I have also tried to regain control of Windows 10 by searching different forums for answers. I've decided to try to delete ***'sethc.exe'*** and replace it with ***'cmd'*** in order to create a new account on Windows 10.

However when I try to delete it i get the following error message:

[image: error message]

*How can i delete* 'sethc.exe' *?* or *How can i get back into my windows 10 ?*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the account you use to log in to the machine is a 'Microsoft' account.

- [Sign in to your Microsoft account](https://account.microsoft.com/about?lang=en-GB&refd=account.live.com&refp=landing), and then select Security.
- Select Change password. Enter your current password, then the new
  password you want, and then enter the new password again.
- Select Save.

(taken directly from :- https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/instantanswers/24749d13-a7ec-4aa7-a067-9fc74c16d8d2/to-change-your-microsoft-account-password)

Comment: I tried that but I made a test account for Outlook and I forgot my password and any info that I made upon registration

Comment: Is there a non-'microsoft account' on the machine, which has administrator priviledges?

Comment: I had a local account with no password on it before I made the microsoft account